# Adding arrays Dynamically in KXmenu for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In the example at [KXMenu repository page](https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmenu/blob/master/KxMenuExample/ViewController.m) , the menu is hardcoded, I need to add dynamic menu items, how can I accomplish that ?

Here is the code that creates the menu items:

```
- (void)showMenu:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        NSArray *menuItems =
        @[

          [KxMenuItem menuItem:@"ACTION MENU 1234456"
                         image:nil
                        target:nil
                        action:NULL],

          [KxMenuItem menuItem:@"Share this"
                         image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"action_icon"]
                        target:self
                        action:@selector(pushMenuItem:)],
          ];



        [KxMenu showMenuInView:self.view
                      fromRect:sender.frame
                     menuItems:menuItems];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found out how to do it, simply by creating an NSMutableArray, initializing it, and using the **addObjectsFromArray** to fill the array

```
NSMutableArray *dynamicMenuItems;
dynamicMenuItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{

    [dynamicMenuItems addObjectsFromArray:@[[KxMenuItem menuItem:@"Share this"
                                                image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"action_icon"]
                                                target:self
                                                action:@selector(pushMenuItem:)
                                                ]]];

}
```